# how to receive a socket message with an empty data?

Tags: python, sockets

i have a socket client and a socket server.

(the server is in python, and is synchroneous.)

sometimes the clients send an empty string. i'm required to identify this situation, and return a response.

with this code, the server just keeps on waiting, and the client's don't get anything in return, unless it sends something mroe "fat" ;)

how can i capture the empty message? is it at all possible?

that's my server code:

```
import SocketServer

def multi_threaded_socket_server():

    class MyRequestHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
        def handle(self):
            while True:
                print 'waiting for client calls...'
                received = self.request.recv( PACKET_SIZE )
                (handle request... )
```

Answer (score 10):

- In TCP, there is no such thing as an empty message, so zero means a peer disconnect.
- In UDP, there is no such thing as a peer disconnect, so zero means an empty datagram.

As you describe a multi-threaded socket server, it would seem to be TCP, in which case your requirement doesn't make sense. You can't send an empty message over TCP. You would have to use a superimposed protocol for everything.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming TCP, you have to design a protocol that indicates when you've received a complete message.  `send()` is not guaranteed to send every byte (check the return value) and `recv()` is not guaranteed to read the number of bytes requested.  In the TCP `recv()` case, receiving zero bytes indicates the socket was closed, so there is no way to send an empty message without metadata (data describing the data).

So design a protocol that includes a way to determine a complete message has been received.  Common ways are to send the size of the message first, or use a special sequence at the end indicating the message is complete.  Also note socket's sendall() method *will* send all the bytes of the message.

Examples:

```
sendall('\x05Hello')  # length first
sendall('Hello\x00')  # nul-termination
sendall('\x00')       # length first, empty message
sendall('\x00')       # empty string, nul-termination.
```

For receiving, buffer recv() calls until a complete message is present.

Receive Algorithm (non-working code):

```
class Handler:

  def __init__(self):
    self.buffer = ''

  def handler(self):
    while True:
      msg = self.get_msg()
      if not msg: break
      process msg

  def get_msg(self):
    if complete message not at the beginning of buffer:
      chunk = recv(1000)
      if not chunk: return '' # socket closed
      buffer += chunk
    remove message from beginning of buffer...update buffer
    return message
```

Answer (score 0):

If the empty string means 0 bytes, the socket library on the client side might ignore it because a packet with 0 data bytes is a disconnect packet.

Comment: The socket library at the client won't even see it, as it will never arrive.

Answer (score -1):

As answered previously, *recv()* returning 0 means "disconnect", so you cannot have a 0-length message.

However, you can get a TCP message that *seems* empty if you only look at it as a string, if what's actually received is a packet starting with a '\0' character.

You can handle this corner case like:

```
received = self.request.recv( PACKET_SIZE )
if received[0]=='\x00':
    <handle empty packet>
```

Comment: A *result of zero* from `recv()` *indicates* a disconnect. A disconnect *segment* in TCP is one that contains a FIN bit. It isn't necessarily zero-length.

Answer (score -2):

*Assuming you're sending packets with python's socket module with TCP/IP ex:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((ip_in, port_in))
```

You cannot use to send an empty message:

```
sock.sendall(bytes("", 'ascii'))
```

Strings sent with TCP/IP are null terminating and look something like:

```
IP packing | TCP packing | string | null ascii character (0x00 in hex)
```

So sending "" will result in:

```
IP packing | TCP packing | 0x00
```

which a TCP server will interpret as a disconnect and the handler will not serve the request.

To send an "empty message" that the server will handle, use something like:

```
sock.sendall(bytes("\00", 'ascii'))
```

which sends a packet that looks like:

```
IP packing | TCP packing | 0x00 | 0x00
```

and the handling would look something like:

```
data = str(self.request.recv(1024), 'ascii')
# data = ""
```

Although all tcp packets use 32bits of data regardless of whether it is used or not, so sending a single null character is not really going to be much of a performance boon.

Comment: Strings sent with TCP/IP are not null terminated. That is done if at all by the sender. Sending `""` will not result in sending anything at all, let alone something that will be interpreted as a disconnect. All TCP packets do not 'use 32 bits of data'. Answer is complete nonsense.